# Grabbing some data off of a page using Node and Cheerio

Tags: javascript, jquery, cheerio

I am trying to get some data from [this](http://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_1918_games.html) page and I am having some troubles.

What I am trying to do on this page is collect all of the data in the first table and save it to a CSV page. My problem is with using Cheerio with node to try and grab the data.

Via the console in chrome (with jquery) I can do the following:

```
$('#div_games table tr[data-row] td').each(function(index) {
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
```

This outputs each `td`'s data in the table which is how I want this. I am trying to replicate this using `cheerio` however it is not working correctly. Here is what I am trying:

```
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var request = require('request');

var url = "http://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_1918_games.html";

request(url, function(err, resp, data){
  if (!err) {
    //console.log(data);
    var $ = cheerio.load(data);

    console.log($("#div_games table tr td").first().data("data-row"));
  }
});
```

This is just returning `undefined`. I am assuming my selector is wrong with Cheerio but I am unsure what is incorrect here?

Comment: The data attributes are added later with javascript as part of the table sorting

Comment: @adeneo do you see an alternate method I could use without using PhantomJS?

Comment: Why is `data-row` important? It's added to all elements by JS, but the rows are available with `#div_games table tr` just fine without it, which seems enough to fulfill your requirement.